# I'm facing this linker command issue in the SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, canvas, linker

```
Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    
    ld: warning: search path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator' not found
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
    ld: Undefined symbols:
      ___llvm_profile_runtime, referenced from:
          ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in `***My project name***`[3](`***My project name***`.dummy.o)
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried deleting the search path as said in this link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663168 but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that can work here is this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973469/14433426 thanks to AkkeyLab for the answer.

The answer involves simple setting that you have to do.

To solve this problem, you may want to add `-fprofile-instr-generate` to *Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags.*